# handle transaction propagation in sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble using SQLAlchemy to handle the propagation level of a transaction. Let me try to explain the problem, which may be verbose only to me.

1. Repository

I was implementing a repository with SQLAlchemy. Like JPARepository, my Repository does things like delete or save entities (SQLALCHEMY MODEL). Roughly, the code looked like this. (part of)

```
class SQLAlchemyFullRepository(CRUDRepositoryABC, ABC, Generic[T]):
    """
    The implementation of CRUDRepositoryABC, with SQLAlchemy.
    this implementation has dependency with flask-sqlalchemy's SQLAlchemy object.
    """

    def __init__(self, db: SQLAlchemy):
        self.db: SQLAlchemy = db
        self._model: SQLAlchemy.Model = self.get_model()

    @abstractmethod
    def get_model(self):
        pass

    def save(self, entity: T) -> T:
        self.db.session.add(entity)
        self.db.session.flush()
        self.db.session.commit()
        return entity

    def save_all(self, entities: List[T]) -> List[T]:
        saved_entities = []
        for entity in entities:
            saved_entity = self.save(entity)
            saved_entities.append(saved_entity)
        return saved_entities
```

2. commit() problem

For example, let's assume that the db.session.commit() code exists in the save() method of my own repository class. This means that if you call the repository's save() method from the outside (in my case, the service layer of the web application), it will be committed immediately, which makes rollback impossible. Because of this problem, I decided to remove the commit() code from the repository, so that the repository would only perform a session.add() on save(), but not a commit.

```
    def save(self, entity: T) -> T:
        self.db.session.add(entity)
        return entity
```

3. Handling transactions in the service layer

So, someone has to perform the commit(). I don't know the Spring Framework very well, but I was aware of the existence of Transactional() and Django's atomic() annotation, and I wanted to implement it. The implemented decorator looks like this.

```
from functools import wraps

from flask import current_app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_sqlalchemy.session import Session


def make_transaction(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        db: SQLAlchemy = current_app.extensions["sqlalchemy"]
        session: Session = db.session
        try:
            print(f"SAVEPOINT STARTS, in {func.__name__}")
            session.begin_nested()
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            session.commit()
            print(f"SAVEPOINT COMMITTED IN {func.__name__}")
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"SAVEPOINT FAILED IN {func.__name__}, with message: {e}")
            session.rollback()
            raise e

    return wrapper
```

It first runs the nested_session before the wrapped function starts, and commits when it finishes. If an exception is thrown when the wrapped function is executed, it will be rolled back.

4. Nested Transactions

The problem is that I wanted to keep the @Transactional method inside the save() of my repository so that it still commits, just like JPARepository does, so I added it as shown below.

```
    @make_transaction
    def save(self, entity: T) -> T:
        self.db.session.add(entity)
        self.db.session.flush()
        return entity
```

5. Problematic situation

As expected, the two successful save() calls are committed immediately, while the outermost level function, save_user(), is rolled back. But this is not what I want.

```
def test_transaction_rollback(test_app, user_repository):
    """
    Tests that the make_transaction method handles the transaction correctly.
    If an error occurs in the wrapped method, the session should be rolled back.
    """
    with test_app.test_request_context():
        user_fullask = UserModel(name="mr_fullask")
        user_spring = UserModel(name="mr_spring")
        with pytest.raises(Exception):

            def raise_exception():
                return 1 / 0

            @make_transaction
            def save_user():
                user_repository.save(user_fullask)
                user_repository.save(user_spring)
                raise_exception()

            save_user()
    with test_app.test_request_context():
        assert UserModel.query.count() == 0
```

[db log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQf5z.png)

In this case, since the child transaction failed, i want to make the parent transaction fail as well.

6. So how do I handle this?

I want to create at least three levels of propagation.

- If the parent transaction fails, all child transactions are rolled back as well.

- If a child transaction fails, the parent transaction is also rolled back.

- If a child transaction fails, the parent transaction succeeds but the child transactions are rolled back.

I've been reading Spring's documentation and SQlalchemy's documentation for a few days, but I can't think of an elegant way to handle this.